# Problem in persian presentation slides

Tags: beamer, presentations, bidi

I'm using a presentation slide template. There is 2 problems with the template which I don't know how to solve.

First: I wrote the supervisor name below the blue box(`\author{‏استاد راهنما }`). I want to put my name up to the supervisor name, but when I use `\author`s two times, it only shows second name.

Second: I have used a list to separate contents:

```
‎‎\tableofcontents‎
\section{‏‎‎‏ماده‌ ‎\hfill}‎
\section{‏پاسخ  ‎\hfill}‎
\subsection{‌تاریخچ  \hfill}
\subsection{آزمایش‌ها \hfill}
\subsection{مدل‌ا \hfill}
\section{ ‏کنشون  ‎\hfill}‎
\section{ ‏همیشه  ‎\hfill}‎
```

At the up right of the pages after the list, it shows last item (همیشه) in bright. I want each page to show the item I'm presenting to be bright, not the last item. Could anyone help? I really appreciate any solutions. The code is as below:

‎

```
    \documentclass{beamer}‎‎‎
    ‎\usetheme{Warsaw}‎
    ‎\usefonttheme{serif}‎
‎    \usepackage{ptext}‎
‎    \usepackage{xepersian}‎
    ‎\settextfont{Yas}‎
    ‎\include{tashih}‎
    ‎\include{commands}‎

    ‎\begin{document}‎

    \title{فلان}
    \subtitle{دارد}
    \author{‏استاد راهنما }
    ‎ \begin{frame}‎
‎     \maketitle‎
     ‎\end{frame}‎
     ‎\begin{frame}‎

     ‎‎\tableofcontents‎
     \section{‏‎‎‏ماده‌ ‎\hfill}‎
    \section{‏پاسخ  ‎\hfill}‎
    \subsection{‌تاریخچ  \hfill}
    \subsection{آزمایش‌ها \hfill}
    \subsection{مدل‌ا \hfill}
    \section{ ‏کنشون  ‎\hfill}‎
    \section{ ‏همیشه  ‎\hfill}‎
    ‎\end{frame}‎
    ‎\begin{frame}‎
    ‎\end{frame}‎

    ‎\begin{frame}‎
    \frametitle{عنوان اسلاید}
    \framesubtitle{زیر عنوان اسلاید}
‎    \end{frame}‎

‎    \begin{frame}‎
    ‎\begin{enumerate}‎
    ‎\item‎ 
    این یک متن است که در اینجا قرار می‌دهیم.
    ‎\end{enumerate}‎

    ‎\begin{itemize}‎
    ‎\item‎ 
    این یک متن است که در اینجا قرار می‌دهیم.
    ‎\end{itemize}‎
    ‎\end{frame}‎
‎    \begin{frame}‎‎
    ‎\ptext[1]‎
    ‎\begin{example}‎
    این یک مثال است.
    ‎\end{example}‎

‎    \begin{definition}‎
    این یک تعریف است.
    ‎\end{definition}‎

    ‎\begin{theorem}‎
    این یک قضیه است.
    ‎\end{theorem}‎
    ‎\end{frame}‎


    ‎\begin{frame}‎
    ‎\begin{columns}‎ 
     ‎\column{.5\textwidth}‎
     ستون شماره ‎۱‎
     ‎\column{.5\textwidth}‎
    ستون شماره ‎۲‎
    ‎\end{columns}‎
    ‎\end{frame}‎


    ‎\begin{frame}‎
    ‎\frametitle{Maths Blocks}‎
‎    \begin{theorem}<1->[Pythagoras]‎ 
‎    $ a^2‎ + ‎b^2 = c^2$‎
    ‎\end{theorem}‎
    ‎\begin{proof}<2->‎
    ‎$\omega‎ +‎\phi = \epsilon $‎
    ‎\end{proof}‎
    ‎\begin{corollary}<3->‎
    ‎$ x‎ + ‎y = y‎ + ‎x  $‎
    ‎\end{corollary}‎
‎    \end{frame}‎

    ‎\begin{frame}‎
     ‎\frametitle{More Lists}‎
‎    \begin{enumerate}[(I)]‎
    ‎\item<1-> Point A‎
    ‎\item<2-> Point B‎
     ‎\begin{itemize}‎
    ‎\item<3-> part 1‎
    ‎\item<4-> part 2‎
    ‎\end{itemize}‎
    ‎\item<5-> Point C‎
    ‎\item<6-> Point D‎
    ‎\end{enumerate}‎
    ‎\end{frame}‎
    ‎%\begin{frame}‎
‎    %\frametitle{Overlays}‎
    ‎%\onslide<1->{First Line of Text}‎
%
    ‎%\onslide<2->{Second Line of Text}‎
%
    ‎%\onslide<3->{Third Line of Text}‎
‎    %\end{frame}‎

‎   \begin{frame}‎
    ‎\frametitle{Overlays}‎
    ‎\only<1>{First Line of Text}‎

    ‎\only<2>{Second Line of Text}‎

    ‎\only<3>{Third Line of Text}‎
    ‎\end{frame}‎

    ‎\setbeamercovered{invisible}‎
    ‎\begin{frame}‎
    ‎\frametitle{Tables}‎
    ‎\end{frame}‎
    ‎\end{document}
```

Comment: Multiple authors are separated by `\and`: `\author{‏استاد راهنما \and همیشه}`.

Comment: Have you tried the `bidipresentation` class?

Comment: Where we can find `tashih` and `commands`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- using `\author{}` two times does not work, as you are overwriting the previous content. A dirty hack could be to insert a linebreak. This can cause problems with the pdf metadata and the footline (the latter can be prevented by giving a short author name with `[your name]`). The cleaner solution would be to redefine the title page to include the additional name
- Putting the `\section` commands right after the table of contents is the wrong place. They should be put inside the presentation at the points where the sections start.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\author[your name]{supervisor \\ your name}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{section 1}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{section 2}
\subsection{subsection 1}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\subsection{subsection 2}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: But there is no subsection or something like that in your code

Comment: @saranj See my edit. Place the subsections in front of the frames where they start.

Comment: Samcarter, how can I write a persian text in beamer? I want it to begin at right.  ‎\begin{frame}‎‎‎
 ‎سی 
 ‎\LTR‎footnote{‎Ci‎‎‎‎}‎‎‎‎
 ‎متن من من م ن م تممتنت مت  تمنت متتن متن تنا نان تن من من م ن م تممتنت مت  تمنت متتن متن تنا نان 
‎‎\end{frame}‎

Comment: also \textbf{سلام} doesn't work :(